# How do I fix vertical label/radio alignment om css?

Tags: css

I am having issues with vertical alignment in firefox/chrome.

For some reason my radio buttons are offset by a couple of pixel.

I can make one of them align but the other will miss-align accordingly

http://www.blueskycouncil.com/details_idea.php?itemid=36

(log in with try/me)

Comment: Looks fine to me on FF 3.6.x on Mac -- http://i53.tinypic.com/viog92.png

Comment: Appears to be something with the .radio ul li label {} css tweaking around the margin-top in there gets me more in line testing in chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...
<li>
    <label>test</label>
    <input type="radio" />
</li>
...

label,input {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
label {
    display:inline; /* display:block; and float:left; are useless */
    margin:0 5px 0 0; /* same for margin-top */
}
input {
    height:auto;
}
```

It should align label and input in most cases.

Comment: Nice! I'd been struggling for hours with the browsers ignoring my layout hints